# Combining Castle Windsor with configuration data

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

In my project I have a few objects that are used as part of multiple services. Following is a brief example of the architecture (interfaces left out intentionally):

```
public class Plc : IPlc
{
    public Plc(string connectionString) { ... }
}

public class PlcRegister
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
}

public class PlcJobWriter : IPlcJobWriter
{
    public PlcJobWriter(IPlc plc,
        PlcRegister commandRegister,
        PlcRegister statusRegister,
        ...)
    { ... }
}

public class JobService : IJobService
{
    public JobService(Dictionary<string, PlcJobWriter> plcJobWriters) { ... }
}

public class PlcProgramWriter : IPlcProgramWriter
{
    public PlcProgramWriter(IPlc plc,
        PlcRegister commandRegister,
        PlcRegister statusRegister,
        ...)
    { ... }
}

public class ProgramService : IProgramService
{
    public ProgramService(List<PlcProgramWriter> plcProgramWriters) { ... }
}
```

What I will get in production is one or more PLC's. Every `Plc` will have one `PlcProgramWriter` and one or more `PlcJobWriter`. Any Program update will be written out to all PlcProgramWriters (thus the `plcProgramWriters` param in `ProgramService` and a job will be written out to the matching `PlcJobWriter`, matched on key in `plcJobWriters` in the `JobService` constructor.

I want the values required for the `Plc` connectionString and the commandRegister and statusRegister for the `PlcJobWriter` and `PlcProgramWriter` configurable through app.config, as well as the keys that the `PlcJobWriter` uses to find the matching JobWriter.

I could just define my own configuration schema and write code to handle the configuration data, but I'm far more interested in what approach I could take if I'd want to have Windsor handle all of it. I don't mind adding infrastructure to make this possible, but I can't find any examples of such a solution at all (probably looking for the wrong stuff).

Comment: Windsor supports XML configuration, which is probably the closest you get out of the box: http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=XML-Registration-Reference&NS=Windsor

Comment: Unfortunately from the minimal documentation on that page I can't make up how to configure this scenario.

Comment: Equally unfortunate is that I don't ever use XML configuration for Windsor. Perhaps this helps? http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/07/AppSettingsconventionforCastleWindsor/ @MarkSeemann would probably be better able to answer this question, to be honest.

Comment: Is it a hard requirement to be able to inject them via Castle, or do you just need typed access to those configuration values?

Comment: Neither of the both. If I can't make it work with Windsor without huge effort, I'll probably just use XDocument and linq-to-xml. However, I expect the same 'problem' in future projects, so if there is a neat solution I'd want to know about it. Also I'm familiar with Spring XML configuration, where you could do all of this in a somewhat comfortable syntax.

Comment: Okay, I'll add something I use as an answer, though it really doesn't answer the question you've posted. Hopefully someone with more knowledge of the XML version comes along at some point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be possible using an approach as follows:

Firstly you will need this in the `configSections` in the web.config. The name can be anything:

```
<section name="castle" type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler, Castle.Windsor" />
```

Then in web.config you create your `castle` section containing your DI config. I've tried to give the best example I can here based on your code and description of your requirements. The important points are that you use the `${ }` syntax to reference other components by their ID, the type names will need to be fully qualified with namespace and assembly, and if you've got more than one implementation defined for each interface then you'll probably have to resolve by key rather than interface type.

```
<castle>
    <properties>
        <connectionString>YourConnectionStringHere</connectionString>
    </properties>

    <components>
         <component id="PlcA" service="Namespace.IPlc, AssemblyName" type="Namespace.Plc, AssemblyName">
             <parameters>
                 <connectionString>${connectionString}</connectionString>
             </parameters>
         </component>
         <!-- Other IPlc implementations as required -->

         <component id="PlcJobWriterA" service="Namespace.IPlcJobWriter, AssemblyName" type="Namespace.PlcJobWriter, AssemblyName">
              <parameters>
                  <plc>${PlcA}</plc>
                  <commandRegister>
                      <parameters>
                          <address>CommandRegisterAddress</address>
                          <length>CommandRegisterLength</length>
                      <parameters>
                   </commandRegister>
                   <statusRegister>
                      <parameters>
                          <address>StatusRegisterAddress</address>
                          <length>StatusRegisterLength</length>
                      <parameters>
                   </statusRegister>
              </parameters>
         </component>
         <!-- Other PlcJobWriters as required -->
         <!-- PlcProgramWriter can be configured in the same way -->

         <component id="JobService" service="Namespace.IJobService, AssemblyName" type="Namespace.JobService, AssemblyName">
             <parameters>
                 <plcJobWriters>
                     <dictionary keyType="System.String" valueType="Namespace.IPlcJobWriter, AssemblyName">
                         <entry key="JobWriterA">${PlcJobWriterA}</entry>
                         <!-- Other entries as required -->
                     </dictionary>
                 </plcJobWriters>  
             </parameters>
         </component>

         <component id="ProgramService" service="Namespace.IProgramService, AssemblyName" type="Namespace.ProgramService, AssemblyName">
             <parameters>
                 <plcProgramWriters>
                     <list>
                         <item>${ProgramWriterA}</item>
                         <!-- Other items as required -->
                     </list>
                 </plcProgramWriters>
             </parameters>
         </component>
    </components>
</castle>
```

You would then pass the name of the config section to your Windsor container when you create it:

```
using Castle.Core.Resource;
using Castle.Windsor;
using Castle.Windsor.Configuration.Interpreters;

...

using (var castleConfig = new ConfigResource("castle"))
{
     container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter(castleConfig));
}
```

Obviously that's not a complete working solution for you but hopefully it should illustrate how to use Castle's XML configuration. Castle's error messages tend to be pretty informative about anything that's amiss. More info can be found here: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.XML-Registration-Reference.ashx

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, will try it right away.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer the question as asked, but if one of your requirements is met by getting typed access to web.config values, then you have two options.

**One,** you could create a class that derives from `ConfigurationSection`, which requires that you register the type in the web.config `<configSections>`, uh, section, like so:

```
<section name="sectionName" type="Fully.Qualified.Namespace.CustomSettings, YourAssemblyName" />
```

and then the section itself looks something like:

```
<customSettings propertyName1="somevalue" />
```

It has the advantage of being able to enforce some rules via data annotations. Here's an implementation I used at one point for an Akismet helper:

```
public class AkismetSettings : ConfigurationSection
{
    private static AkismetSettings settings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("akismet") as AkismetSettings;

    public static AkismetSettings Settings
    {
        get
        {
            return settings;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("key", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Key
    {
        get { return (string)this["key"]; }
        set { this["key"] = value; }
    }


    [ConfigurationProperty("registeredsite", IsRequired = true)]
    public string RegisteredSite
    {
        get { return (string)this["registeredsite"]; }
        set { this["registeredsite"] = value; }
    }
}
```

with its relevant section:

```
<akismet key="0000000000" registeredsite="http://example.com/" />
```

I would then use it like so:

```
var helper = new AkismetHelper(AkismetSettings.Settings.Key, AkismetSettings.Settings.RegisteredSite);
```

I didn't have a persistent need for the helper, and it seemed like overkill to resolve an instance via Windsor, so I just new'd one up when I needed it.

**Two,** the option I prefer, is to simply create a class that reads the relevant values from `<appSettings>` and does the necessary type conversion.

Here's a trimmed-down version from what I'm using at the moment.

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public static int MinPasswordLength
    {
        get
        {
            //  Recommended minimum password length.
            //  See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_length_%26_complexity
            int min = 8;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["app.minPasswordLength"]))
            {
                min = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["app.minPasswordLength"]);
            }

            return min;
        }
    }

    /* ... */

    public static string Find(string key)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key] ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

You could use the same idea to write a somewhat cleaner accessor for the `<connectionStrings>` section. If you want to use `<appSettings>`, but don't want a lot of values in the web.config, it helps to remember that `<appSettings>` has a `file` attribute that can be used to link to another `.config` file that also contains an `<appSettings>` section:

```
<appSettings file="settings.config">
```

Comment: Thanks for the good examples. As you said it's not really an answer to the question, it's also not entirely applicable to my configuration options. I'm strongly considering the outside-of-Windsor option now, I'll post my implementation if that's what I'll end up doing.